# Counting commutative rngs (rings without identity)

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

[A037289](https://oeis.org/A037289) counts the number of commutative rngs (rings without identity). It is complete up to 31, that is, the number of commutative rngs with 32 elements is not known. Is this in the literature?

[Asymptotics](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.13215) suggests there should be around 4000 to 20,000.